# String formatting with nested dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary, formatting

My setup is the following. I have a nested dictionary

```
dic1 = { 0 : 'a', dic2: { 2 : 'b', 3: 'c' } }
```

and a string

```
s = 'The first letter is %(0)s and the third is %(dic2[2])s'
```

Of course, the following doesn't work :

```
print (s % dic1)
```

What's then the proper way of doing that?

---

*Note:* I'm aware of the question [String formating with nested dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33161690/4003761), but I believe my problem cannot be solved by looping over the dictionaries. The above is of course a very simplified version of my actual problem, and I need both to respect the formatting of `dic1` and call the print statement only once.

---

**EDIT**:

As pointed out in the comments, I was indeed a bit hasty about my simplifications...

```
dic2 = { 2: 'b', 3: 'c'}
dic1 = { 0: 'a', 'dic2': dic2}
```

Comment: where is `dic2`  defined ?

Comment: Your `dic1` is not valid, unless `dic2` is some variable name for a hashable type.

Comment: Have you considered using `str.format` instead of the old-fashioned `%` mechanism?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre see edit.

Comment: @jonrsharpe How would I do that?

Comment: Have you read the docs or a tutorial? They'd show you.

Comment: Are your keys actually numbers? Because that complicates things.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga The keys are actually strings - didn't think that would make too much of a difference, sorry!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the keys are strings, this could work:

```
>>> dic2 = { 'b': 2, 'c': 3}
>>> dic1 = { 'a': 1, 'dic2': dic2}
>>> s = 'The first number is {a} and the third is {dic2[c]}'
>>> s.format(**dic1)
'The first number is 1 and the third is 3'
```

If not, this works (I just discovered this actually):

```
>>> dic2 = { 2: 'b', 3: 'c'}
>>> dic1 = { 0: 'a', 'dic2': dic2}
>>> s = 'The first number is {dic1[0]} and the third is {dic1[dic2][3]}'
>>> s.format(dic1=dic1)
'The first number is a and the third is c'
>>>
```

Comment: VERY good. I don't understand how this works. It _has_ to use `eval` right?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I assume it's some sort of dark sorcery. My experience with Python is, if you are hoping something will work, it just might.

Comment: I've attempted to explain that sorcery.

Comment: Example1: If the keys are strings, In python 3.11.1, it is not working. what is the workaround?

Comment: @vishnu all the code above works exactly the same in Python 3.11 when I check it right now. Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: Yes it is working, I printed the 's' directly after the s.format line in a file, so it printed the template string as output. When f-string is used along with .format, the result is not the same.

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't specify a version, I'm going to assume the lastest version of Python (3.6). It's simple:

```
dic1 = { 0 : 'a', 'dic2': { 2 : 'b', 3: 'c' } }

print(f"The first letter is {dic1[0]} and the third is {dic1['dic2'][2]}")
```

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on `@juanpa.arrivillaga's` answer:

With

```
 In [884]: dic2 = { 2: 'b', 3: 'c'}
 ...: dic1 = { 0: 'a', 'dic2': dic2}

In [894]: '{d[0]}, {d[dic2][3]}'.format(d=dic1)
Out[894]: 'a, c'
In [895]: dic1[0]
Out[895]: 'a'
In [896]: dic1['dic2'][3]
Out[896]: 'c'
```

The `format` method in 894 gets a reference to `dic1`, and names it `d`.  Then expressions in the `{}` are evaluated using that dictionary.

Alternatively the dictionary accessing could be done on the right, and strings passed to the format string:

```
In [897]: '{}, {}'.format(dic1[0], dic1['dic2'][3])
Out[897]: 'a, c'
```

This works with the old style formatting, which takes a tuple of values:

```
In [898]: '%s, %s'%(dic1[0], dic1['dic2'][3])
Out[898]: 'a, c'
```

==============

The dictionary can also be referenced by position:

```
'{0[0]}, {1[dic2][3]}'.format(dic1,dic1)
```

[str format examples](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-examples)